# Two columns that are parallel when there's room and centered over each other when there isn't

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put together some html and css to make it happen like this:

I have left and right blocks of text. When there's room, I want the left text left-justified and the right text right-justified. When there isn't room, I want the left centered over the right. Like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Left block of text         Block of text on the right

-----------------------------
     Left block of text
 Block of text on the right
```

Catch: This is for an email, and I want it to work in GMail, which to the best of my knowledge doesn't give me any way to use media queries.

I tried

```
<div style="float: left; text-align: center">Left block of text</div>
<div style="float: right; text-align: center">Block of text on the right</div>
```

That works for the "wide" case, but in a narrow window I get

```
Left block of text
    Block of text on the right
```

The centering just doesn't come into affect. I tried setting widths and max-widths every way I could think of and I just can't come up with something that works.

Any helpful ideas?

Comment: it is possible through 1 break point if you have any please specify.then i might try for your help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "1 break point". If you mean, there is some screen size at which it should jump from "parallel" to "stacked", then yes. Ideally this would be when it no longer fits on one line, but I could use a fixed pixel width that is a little above that point.

Comment: by 1 break point i meant that, if you could fix a width like say 768px. so `all devices below 768 px will have stacked` and `all devices above it will have parallel view.` this case is possible.

Comment: @karanthakkar Ok, yes, I can do that. It's about 450px.

Comment: can you check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mn32w/ and tell me its fine or some modifications needed.

Comment: @karanthakkar That's pretty good -- you should post that as an answer. It's not QUITE what my client asked for, but they might accept it. A small catch is that the blocks are not left and right justified on a wide screen but centered within their half, but I think that's acceptable. Bigger problem: as the screen gets small enough, the min-width prevents it from wrapping to the screen size, and instead text gets cut off. Still, this is better than I was able to come up with. Thanks.

Comment: min width is 225px right. so if screen width is below 225px text will get cut off. but standard min device width is 320px if I'm not wrong. so on any device it will look good. please point it out if I'm wrong anywhere. :)

Comment: one more thing you can add `word-wrap: break-word;` if your block text size is huge you can try http://jsfiddle.net/Mn32w/3/ (looks perfect in small screen but in wide its pretty odd)or `word-break: break-all;` (looks good but breaks the word) as per needs. try both. (this is only if your text is very large else avoid this comment)

Comment: @karanthakkar My text isn't huge. Left text is basically "Copyright 2014 by My Client Corporation all rights reserved" and  and right text is a couple of links to another web site of theirs.

Comment: i hope you have found some solution. if you can post fiddle,if will be helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

[js.fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uv42T/)

```
#right{
    text-align: right !important;
}

div{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 49%;
}
```

is this somewhat what you wanted?

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid that doesn't work. At wide widths, it just puts the left text flush left with the right text immediately after; and at narrow widths it puts the left text flush left with the right text immediately below.